# Laravel Pass Variables to 'master.blade'

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a file called 'master.blade.php' that has the menu, and main aspects of my website. I then have files using @extends and @sections. I know how to pass variables using @extends

```
@extends('master', ['settings' => $settings])
```

However I am unsure how to pass a variable to the master without having  to this on every single page. Is there anyway to do this without having to do it on every page that uses the master? Something like middleware or along those lines?

Comment: I would create a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers), that way you could share the settings only with the _master_ view. While STA's answer below works it will share the settings with every view, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boot method from `AppServiceProvider` :

```
public function boot() {
     View::share('settings', 'value');
 }
```

See official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Or if you want to pass only master :

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('layouts.master', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('settings', 'value');
    });
}
```